# How can I change entries in a list of lists depending on the entries in the list itself?

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I have an 3D dimensional Array of data. It has this kind of strucuture: {i,x,y}

```
{{1, 1, 6}, {2, 2, 4}, {3, 3, 5}, {4, 4, 7}, {5, 5, 2}, {6, 6, 5}, {7,
   8, 2}, {8, 9, 7}, {9, 10, 6}, {10, 13, 6}, {11, 14, 7}, {12, 15, 
  3}, {13, 16, 6}, {14, 18, 3}, {15, 21, 1}, {16, 22, 3}, {17, 23, 
  4}, {18, 24, 2}, {19, 26, 4}, {20, 28, 6}, {21, 29, 6}, {22, 31, 
  2}, {23, 33, 5}, {24, 34, 5}, {25, 35, 5}, {26, 36, 5}, {27, 38, 
  3}, {28, 40, 7}}
```

I want to change only the w column of the data in this way:
Lets say we are at the i´th row: {i,v,w} and the next is the i+1 row: {i+1,y,z} The rule should be:

```
   If v+w>=y then w->y - 1 - v Else nothing
```

And for the last row, where there isnt any y the y should be v1+n. The very first v1 plus some kind of a number. Meaning the last v->y1+n - 1 - v
This is very confusing so I will give an example:
Lets say the starting array is:

```
   {{1,5,3},{2,7,4},{3,8,0},{4,10,3},{5,14,7}} n=15;
```

Then the resulting array would be:

```
   {{1,5,1},{2,7,0},{3,8,0},{4,10,3},{5,14,5}}
```

And the second part of the problem would be only changing the v column:

```
   v->v+w
```

Comment: Check the document of `BlockMap`.

Comment: @xzczd this doesnt work for the last element of the list. Also BlockMap unfortunately doesnt process "If" functions :C

Comment: Just append an extra element at the end and remove it afterwards, or use `MapAt` to handle the last element. "Also BlockMap unfortunately doesnt process "If" functions" I don't think so. How do you use it?

Comment: If you don't know how to define function in _Mathematica_, start from https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsAndPrograms.html Also, your `blax`, `bla(x+1)`, `blay` notation is just terrible, please improve it.

Comment: It looks to me like your example indicates the rule: `If blax+blay>=bla(x+1) then blay->bla(x+1) - 1 - blax Else blax->0`

Comment: @xzczd Okay I will take a look at the `MapAt` thank you. This is how I defined my function for the `BlockMap` : `f[{{u_,v_,w_},{x_,y_,z}}]=If[v+w>=y,{u,v,y-1-v},{u,v,w}]`  and this is how I defined the `BlockMap:  BlockMap[f,data,2,1]`

Comment: @DanielHuber  We have those entries in the array: `...{3,8,0},{4,10,3}...` which become `...{3,8,0},{4,10,3}...` 8+0<10 so we are in the Else case, and the blax stays 8 and not 0.

Comment: It should be `f[{{u_,v_,w_},{x_,y_,z_}}]`

Comment: @xzczd ahh yes, that was a typo sorry. It works now. I dont know why (maybe a typo maybe some kind of conceptual mistake maybe something with quit kernel) but earlier, the function didnt evaluate the expressions. If the input was `{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}` then its output was `If[2+3>=5,{1,2,5-1-2},{1,2,3}]` thank you very much for your help I really appreciate it :)

Comment: …Did you add `Defer` in your code?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a helper function:

```
f[block : {{_, a2_, a3_}, {_, b2_, _}}] :=
  If[a2 + a3 >= b2, ReplacePart[block[[1]], 3 -> b2 - 1 - a2], block[[1]]]
```

We can use this with `BlockMap`, but we need to append the dummy value:

```
BlockMap[f, Append[test, {0, test[[1, 2]] + Length[Flatten[test]], 0}], 2, 1]
```

where `test` is

```
test = {{1, 5, 3}, {2, 7, 4}, {3, 8, 0}, {4, 10, 3}, {5, 14, 7}}
```